# I have 8 categories I need to classify them using matlabta svm code

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I have 8 categories I need to classify them using matlabta svm I need to guess the objects but the samples on the internet are very mixed and can help me if there is any way I can share a code to learn.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are doing.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/deep-learning-for-computer-vision-with-matlab.html

I have to do something like this

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/deep-learning-for-computer-vision-with-matlab.html

I have to do something like this

Comment: I need to classify 8 catagories using svm 3 feature vectors I have 8 target variables

Comment: @HilalGüven Please add updates and clarification directly to your original question by using the [edit] link at the bottom of the question (below the tags).